Android app that connects to NRF52840 with BLE
I'm completely new to Android development, but am working on an app that connects to the NRF52840 board with BLE. I have no idea where to start, threw some code together and felt even more lost, would appreciate if anyone could point me towards good resources or some pre-built apps with BLE connectivity!
Thanks!

Welcome to StackOverfow. This site works best with specific programming problems and not 'can someone help me' / 'how do i learn' type questions. If that is what you are looking for you would be better off on a different social media site. While the wiki tag for Android has some resources, asking is considered off-topic. Please read how to ask.

Nordic Semiconductor provides some Android apps for developers to test their devices. The most flexible one is nRF Connect for Mobile, but this one is not open source.
Instead, I can recommend the nRF Toolbox app or the nRF Device Manager app, both of which have open source code on git that you can download, change and build yourself.

Working with BLE in Android can be pretty overwhelming. There are a lot of things that need to be taken care of. I'll try to list down a few points that you can begin exploring.
Learn Android Permission basics and how to request permission dynamically from the official documentation.
Explore nrf connect app to see how BLE interactions are carried out and what prerequisites you need to make it work with your device. (Service UUID, read/write Characteristic UUID, etc)
You can explore a few existing libraries for BLE interactions in Android as shared by @Tejash.
You can go through this post I've written for a beginner's guide to working with BLE in Android.
I hope this helps you to get started with a basic Android app for BLE operations.


Learn BLE basics (Central/Peripheral, Services/Characteristics) and Android Studio setup.
Explore BLE APIs (BluetoothManager, BluetoothAdapter, BluetoothGatt) or use libraries like RxAndroidBle.
Experiment with Nordic tools like nRF Connect to understand BLE communication.
Build a simple app to scan for BLE devices, connect to NRF52840, and read a characteristic.

